# Table content overflow to other divs

Tags: html, css

I have a small perl script that generates html and constructs the actual HTML code, however the contents that are generated (which are in html) are overflowing into the other tables on the page.

```
my $lwpcurl = LWP::Curl->new();
my $content = $lwpcurl->get('http://panewsalerts.us/ticker.php?alerts=20','http://www.alertpage.net/live.htm');
$content =~ s/^(?:.*\n){1,4}//;
print ($content);
```

My 'mapshow' div has the following:

```
div.mapshow
{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-style:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:none;
    top:0;
    margin-left:50%;
}
```

When I add the output code in the div, ie:

```
<div class=mapshow style=\"width:49%;\">
<div> (data from perl script output that is in HTML </div>
```

The table data overflows/spills over into the other tables. Anyway to fix it? I've tried adjusting the overflow to auto and hidden and haven't had much luck.

You can see an output of the code by going to

```
http://panewsalerts.us/ticker.php?alerts=20
```

Comment: So overflow does'nt work if you don't have width or height defined. Make a fiddle if you can_ your link doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your output code there is only one table.

Try using

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

And also maybe word-break or wrap.